# Как настроить в .properties log4j путь к логам внутри проекта?

Tags: java, log4j

Как настроить в .properties log4j путь к логам внутри проекта?
То есть что бы после пула с гита путь был всегда октуален.

#### [log4j.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDnMO.png)

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,infoLogfile, errorLogFile, stdout

#Error Logger option
log4j.logger.com.testNgExample.tests=errorLogFile

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.infoLogfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.infoLogfile.File=/Users/mu/Dev/Auto_test/my_example/src/test/log/Log.txt
log4j.appender.infoLogfile.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.infoLogfile.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.infoLogfile.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.infoLogfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.infoLogfile.layout.ConversionPattern=line:%L - [%-5p][%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] %c{1}: - %m%n

# Direct logError messages to a log file
log4j.appender.errorLogFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.errorLogFile.File=/Users/mu/Dev/Auto_test/my_example/src/test/log/logError.txt
log4j.appender.errorLogFile.threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.errorLogFile.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.errorLogFile.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.errorLogFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.errorLogFile.layout.ConversionPattern=line:%L - [%-2p][%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [%t] %c{5}.%M.%F.%M: - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=line:%L - [%-5p][%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] %c{1}: - %m%n
```

Answer (score 1):

Из пути надо убрать лишнее

```
log4j.appender.infoLogfile.File=log/Log.txt
```

тогда лог будет создаваться в папке `log` относительно текущей папки.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.